# Change the color of the UIButton when its state is .disabled

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I'm trying to change the button image color when it's disabled. To mention that my button may be also enabled

The thing is it's always grey.

```
    sendCodeBtn.isEnabled = false
    sendCodeBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "validated_phone").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .disabled)
    sendCodeBtn.tintColor = Theme.defaultColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

If you want to do this programmatically (it doesn't look pretty, but possible):

```
func changeDisableButtonColor(button: UIButton, color: UIColor) {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: myButton.frame.width, height: myButton.frame.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context?.fill(rect)
    
    let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .disabled)
}
```

Usage:

```
changeDisableButtonColor(button: myButton, color: .red)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction btn : UIButton!
if btn.state == .isSelected{
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change all properties of an UIButton in the **storyboard**.

Change the state like in the image:

[image]

and then set the properties like colors and image.

Or **programmatically**:

With image:

```
sendCodeBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"), for: .disabled)
```

With background color:

```
sendCodeBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor .red
```

Comment: the thing is I prefer to do it programmatically since the first time it's enabled

Answer (score 0):

In **swift** you can do this in several ways -

```
@IBAction func onClickButtonStateChanged(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.isSelected){
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red  //Highlighted
    }else{
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.grey . // disabled
    }
}
```

Or

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.red : UIColor.grey  // selected : disabled 
    }
}
```

Another way -

```
   button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button_image"), for: .normal)
   button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button_image_selected"), for: .selected)
   button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button_image_selected"), for: .disabled)
   button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "button_image_selected"), for: [.selected, .highlighted])
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the button only by changing the **isEnabled** property value you can add observer like this:

```
btnConfirm.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIButton.isEnabled), options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    btnConfirm.backgroundColor = btnConfirm.isEnabled ? .red : .lightGray
}
```

And then change only the **isEnabled** property to change the background color.